# How do I keep TABLE HTML format in Gmail with Google Spreadsheet contents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to develop a script which is to automatically send email which will include the table from a google spreadsheet and I want to keep the original table format/color in the email as well.
To do that, I have used UrlFetchApp and mailApp like following:

```
var url = 'my google doc publish url';
var requestData = googleOAuth_('docs','https://docs.google.com/feeds/');
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, requestData);
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var html = response.getContentText();
MailApp.sendEmail(me, 'Email subject', 'no html :( ', {'htmlBody':html});
```

And this actually works, I can receive the email with all the table data I need. However, all table format and color information are lost in the email. Further investigation shows that could be because Gmail does not support `<style> </style>` tag while doing HTML rendering. And unfortunately the published google spreadsheet is using that. Following is a example:

```
<div id="content"><style>.tblGenFixed td {padding:0 3px;overflow:hidden;white-space:normal;letter-spacing:0;word-spacing:0;background-color:#fff;z-index:1;border-top:0px none;border-left:0px none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px solid #CCC;} .dn {display:none} .tblGenFixed td.s0 {background-color:#b6d7a8;font-family:calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif;font-size:100.0%;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;direction:auto-ltr;white-space:normal;overflow:hidden;border-top:1px solid #000000;border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;border-left:1px solid #000000;} .tblGenFixed td.s2 {background-color:#b6d7a8;font-family:calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif;font-size:100.0%;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;direction:auto-ltr;white-space:normal;overflow:hidden;border-top:1px solid #000000;border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;} .tblGenFixed td.s1 {background-color:#b6d7a8;font-family:calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif;font-size:100.0%;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;direction:auto-ltr;white-space:normal;overflow:hidden;border-top:1px solid #000000;border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;} </style><table dir='ltr' border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class='tblGenFixed' id='tblMain'><tr class='rShim'><td class='rShim' style='width:0;'><td class='rShim' style='width:121px;'><td class='rShim' style='width:353px;'><td class='rShim hdn' style='display:none;width:62px;'><td class='rShim' style='width:87px;'><tr dir='ltr'><td class=hd><p style='height:50px;'>.</td><td  dir='ltr' class='s0'>Key<td  dir='ltr' class='s1'>Summary<td  dir='ltr' class='s2 dn'>Labels<td  dir='ltr' class='s2'>Status</tr></table></div>
```

However, if I tried to copy and paste the table from google spreadsheet to Gmail, it actually shows correctly on both sender and receiver side which confuse me. So I use GmailApp to check the HTML source there.

```
var drafts = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
var body = drafts[i].getBody();
MailApp.sendEmail('example@google.com','test email','no html',{htmlBody:body});
```

And from debug, i can observe the HTML content of this email (by copy&paste table directly from google spreadsheet to gmail composer) is something like following:

```
<div dir=""ltr""><table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" dir=""ltr"" style=""table-layout:fixed;font-size:13px;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif""><colgroup><col width=""121""><col width=""353""><col width=""87""><col width=""113""><col width=""74""></colgroup><tbody><tr style=""height:51px"">
<td style=""vertical-align:bottom;direction:ltr;background-color:rgb(182,215,168);font-family:calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);padding:0px 3px"">Key</td>
<td style=""border-bottom-width:1px;border-top-style:solid;direction:ltr;background-color:rgb(182,215,168);border-right-style:solid;font-weight:bold;padding:0px 3px;border-bottom-color:rgb(0,0,0);border-top-width:1px;vertical-align:bottom;border-bottom-style:solid;border-top-color:rgb(0,0,0);border-right-color:rgb(0,0,0);border-right-width:1px;font-family:calibri,arial,sans,sans-serif"">Summary</td>
```

So I believe Gmail has done some auto-conversion when the paste happens. So my question will be how I can do the similar conversion using Google script?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way to do it from gas. You would need to get each cell format and translate it into a html table which is not trivial (merged cells and other nontrivial conversions).